# SQL Row Order based on Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to implement an order column based on THREADPK1 and Date columns in my query.

Example Results (with desired column on end called date_position :

```
ThreadSourceKey   CourseNumber         Date      ReadCount   Date Position
1518055            0701117023LFC    2016-08-24      18            1
1522610            0701117023LFC    2016-08-24      2             1
5443433            0701117023LFC    2016-08-25      1             1
5443433            0701117023LFC    2016-08-27      1             2
5443344            0701117023LFC    2016-08-21      1             1
5443344            0701117023LFC    2016-08-20      1             2
```

This is my query: Interested to know how to incorporate the ordering of Date position.

```
SELECT DISTINCT rs.threadsourcekey, 
                dc.coursenumber, 
                CONVERT (DATE, rs.modifieddate, 103) AS 'Date', 
                Sum(rs.recentreadcount)              AS ReadCount 
FROM   customfinal.rsreportingfactforumreadcounts rs 
       INNER JOIN #threads threads 
               ON rs.threadsourcekey = threads.threadsourcekey 
       INNER JOIN final.dimcourse dc 
               ON rs.coursekey = dc.coursekey 
WHERE  rs.coursekey = @CourseKey 
       AND rs.modifieddate >= Dateadd(day, -7, @DefaultDate) 
       AND rs.usersourcekey >- 1 
       AND rs.recentreadcount <> 0 
GROUP  BY rs.threadsourcekey, 
          dc.coursenumber, 
          CONVERT (DATE, rs.modifieddate, 103)
```

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using.

Comment: Look for `ROW_NUMBER` window function

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with your current query, and describe what output you want?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - I guess he wants to generate `Date Position` column

Comment: Current query is fine, however I am wanting to understand how to add another column [Date Position] which is displayed in the example output. The query posted produces this output however I want to add the additional column [Date Position] to display the distinct date order.. So first line in output has its own thread key and date so the date position is 1, the line with thread key 5443433 has two rows with two diff dates (the 25th and 27th) so the date position for the 25th = 1 and the 27th = 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
ThreadSourceKey,
CourseNumber,
[Date],
ReadCount,
Date_Position = row_number() over (partition by ThreadSourceKey order by [Date])
from
(your sql statement) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query works fine, adding [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) should get you what you want.

Note that since your `GROUP BY` has `CONVERT (DATE, rs.modifieddate, 103)` you need to use exactly that to partition by.

```
SELECT DISTINCT rs.threadsourcekey, 
                dc.coursenumber, 
                CONVERT (DATE, rs.modifieddate, 103) AS 'Date', 
                Sum(rs.recentreadcount)              AS ReadCount,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by rs.threadsourcekey order by CONVERT (DATE, rs.modifieddate, 103)) AS [DATE POSITION]

FROM   customfinal.rsreportingfactforumreadcounts rs 
       INNER JOIN #threads threads 
               ON rs.threadsourcekey = threads.threadsourcekey 
       INNER JOIN final.dimcourse dc 
               ON rs.coursekey = dc.coursekey 
WHERE  rs.coursekey = @CourseKey 
       AND rs.modifieddate >= Dateadd(day, -7, @DefaultDate) 
       AND rs.usersourcekey >- 1 
       AND rs.recentreadcount <> 0 
GROUP  BY rs.threadsourcekey, 
          dc.coursenumber, 
          CONVERT (DATE, rs.modifieddate, 103)
```

Here is a snippet if you want to pick at and see how it works.

```
SELECT  threadsourcekey, 
        ModDate AS 'Date', 
        Sum(ReadCount)              AS ReadCount ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by threadsourcekey order by ModDate) AS [DATE POSITION]
FROM   
    ( VALUES 
        (1518055,          '2016-08-24',      1),
        (1518055,          '2016-08-24',      1),
        (1518055,          '2016-08-24',      1),  
        (1522610,          '2016-08-24',      1),
        (1522610,          '2016-08-24',      1), 
        (5443433,          '2016-08-25',      1),
        (5443433,          '2016-08-27',      1),
        (5443344,          '2016-08-21',      1),
        (5443344,          '2016-08-20',      1)
    ) As Tbl (ThreadSourceKey, ModDate,     ReadCount)

GROUP  BY threadsourcekey,           
          ModDate
```